# How to change JQuery Dialog css top value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jquery dialog that I am wanting to change the value of the css top to 50px. I have a link that opens the dialog and the onclick calls a js function that is supposed to change the top value of the dialog, then changes the inner html, and then opens the dialog.

HTML:

```
<a onclick="linkClicked(); $('#myDialog').html('Loading...'); $('#myDialog').dialog('open'); return false;" href="#">Click Me</a>

<div id="myDialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Test.</p>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#myDialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
    });
});
</script>
```

JS:

```
function linkClicked() {
    $("#myDialog").parent().css({'top': '50px'});
    console.log($("#myDialog").parent());
}
```

Here is my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kgjes8xs/

Once again my question is How do I change the top style value of a dialog from a js function?

Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the Function to the end of the onClick like so

```
<a onclick="$('#myDialog').html('Loading...'); $('#myDialog').dialog('open'); linkClicked();return false;" href="#">Click Me</a>
```

I've tried this on the fiddle and it works fine, logically you have to run the postioning after the opening of the dialog.

Comment: This is correct- wait for the modal to open before applying your styles as the modal applies it's own styles. Alternatively, set a style the modal would not override- like margin-top.

Comment: Worked! Thank you for the fast response. Once I can give you credit for the answer I will. I have to wait 7 minutes before accepting an answer.